# Text wrapping round a figure equivalent to Word’s Tight wrapping

Tags: header-footer, wrap, shapepar

To comply with the visual requirements of a grant, I should like to include the logo of the grant in the footer of each page and have the text wrap round it tightly as in the picture:
[image]

One can easily do that in Word, by selecting `Tight wrap` for a picture placed in the footer. But for several reasons I do not wish to migrate my document from LaTeX to Word.

Is it possible to accomplish this in LaTeX? My searches have led me to `shapepar`, but what I have found tells me that it is for a single paragraph that I have to format manually, whereas in this scenario I have no previous knowledge which paragraph will be at the bottom to interact with the figure in the footer.

Your thoughts are much appreciated.